# How to play a region locked xbox 360 game and use my region's account on it?

Tags: xbox-360, region-lock

So I realized that their have been a lot of xbox 360 games made in Europe & Japan that haven't made it to the US.

I found out though that setting up a PAL or NTSC-J xbox 360 to play these games in the US isn't too difficult though.

My question is once the hardware is set up, can an xbox account in the US region still be downloaded or transferred to the foreign xbox?

I know that xbox accounts can't change region, I was just hoping I could get my US account on the foreign xbox to get achievements for the foreign game I wanted to play.

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to be the same as what you are actually asking. Perhaps you should consider a title more accurate to what you are asking or revise your question to more closely fit what the title is asking.

Comment: A fair number of Xbox 360 games are *already* region-free, even though they're labeled as PAL or NTSC-J versions (in fact, no modern console has any *technical* reason to implement region locking; it's done for other reasons). [Play-Asia](http://www.play-asia.com/paOS-00-3-xbox360_compatibility_guide-49-en.html) has a pretty thorough list of compatibility results, so check that before you invest money in a foreign console.

Comment: @skovacs1: I would have flagged as off-topic if I hadn't actually read the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### How do you play a region-locked xbox 360 game?

**You can play a region-locked xbox 360 game on a console for that region** as you have already figured out. The three regions are generally identified by the different output standards that they support in those regions of NTSC, NTSC-J, and PAL.

### Can an xbox account in the US region exist on a foreign console?

This seems to be your real question. You should consider changing the title. The short answer is **yes.** Also to address what seems to be your primary concern, **achievements that you earn on your foreign console can be added to your gamertag, regardless of what region it is from.**

See [this thread about stacking achievements](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-124009.html). The relevant post is as follows:

> ... So if I buy a PAL360(which is Europe)and get a copy of German Bioshock. All I need to do is attach my harddrive to the PAL360 and get more achievements for playing the same game, hence stackable. Is this correct?
>
> Yes, but for the convenience of use you can simple store your profile in a Memory Unit and use it between 2 consoles, each one with its HDD.
>
> You have to log with you normal account every time you play the games in different consoles, to earn the achievements.

So, simply put, **you just copy your profile over to the other console** either using an HDD or memory stick and sign in as normal. With the advent of the ability to have a cloud save of your profile, it may be possible to copy your profile over by simply using the internet, but I haven't read anything to confirm this yet.

Comment: Not sure, but cloud based profiling may make even the "copy" method unnecessary, if you have internet access.  Not sure if that creates other problems.  I have two Xbox 360s and regularly switch between them with no "copy" step.  I just set up the cloud based login feature.

Comment: I very much doubt only supporting one output mode is the real cause for region locks.

Comment: @kotekzot I never said it was the "real" reason. I said it was largely necessary. This was moreso true prior to digital output though and doesn't really contribute much to the answer, especially if the "real" reason is one of the more likely reasons related to profit or something else. As such, I shall edit that portion out of the answer.

Comment: @EBongo You make a good point, but I haven't read anything about using cloud copies for this method and cannot guarantee that it will work. I don't see a reason that it could create other problems though as it is doing the same thing that you would be doing manually. I will add a note of your idea to the answer.